# Xcode 12.3 puts any new piece of content in a new preview

Tags: xcode, swiftui

[image: Xcode preview screenshots]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
        Text("World")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The code above results in two preview windows: one with text "Hello", second window holds "World"

Every time I add something like Text() or whatever, it appears in the second preview window. Adding more elements automatically leads to new preview windows. THe code in the PreviewProvider remains the same, so it's not duplicate previews, it just the separate previews for EACH element...

I tried to restart Xcode, change simulator devices, create new projects - nothing changes.

It started after I added duplicate preview in one project and then deleted it by removing appropriate lines in the PreviewProvider. After that all new projects or all new files in old projects show this strange behaviour.

Comment: I would assume this is happening because `body` normally makes the assumption that if you're returning multiple elements like this that you want them in a `VStack`, but the preview isn't smart enough for that.  If you wrap your two text views in a `VStack`, does the problem disappear?

Comment: This is expected behaviour. As @jnpdx says, wrap your content in a `VStack`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help. I thought I've broken something, but it appears everything is fine. I haven't used SwiftUI for almost a year...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `body` by default is a `@ViewBuilder` in SwiftUI 2.0, so it just generate a group of views inline, thus having two Text element you got two previews. If you want just one Preview your `body` should have the one top view, like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      HStack {
        Text("Hello")
        Text("World")
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the two `Text` elements into a Container, like e.g. a `VStack`.